# In a mongodb group/map command determine the group's percentage of a total

Tags: mongodb

In a mongodb group operation, is their a way to determine totals during finalization, for eaxample to determine the groups percentage of the collection's total.

For example, after the grouping operation is completed, I know that group A has an aggregate qty of 50. 
Is their a way to get the group's qty values as a percentage of the total?

Or do I have to save results to a collection, determine the totals, then go back and update each document with a calculated percentage of the total for the group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB map-reduce supports a `scope` field, which sets Javascript globals available to `map`, `reduce`, and `finalize` functions. You could add a field to `scope` and track the total during either `map` or `reduce` phases, whichever makes most sense for your use case; you can then access this during `finalize` to compute the percentage for each output group.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is exactly what I need. Do you have a reference for an example using the scope variable from within the function, the github example on the mongodb site passes scope :{xx:0}, but does show how to get at it from within the function, and I haven't been able to connect the dots.

Comment: Scope variables become javascript globals. You can access them by name (in this case, `xx`) from within the `map`, `reduce`, or `finalize` functions.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed to know. This opens up a whole lot of solutions for me (without dynamically generating javascript!)  I should have taken 'scope' more literally.

Comment: scope variables are supposed to be read-only - if you were running this sharded, you would find that their value resets to initialized value on every shard (and when merging results)