# How to use scope variables as property names in a Mongo Map/Reduce emit

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

There is a [question (and answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273379/how-to-use-variables-in-mongodb-map-reduce-map-function) that deals with the general case. I am having difficulty using a scope variable as a field key (as opposed to the field value)

In the example below all the FULLY_CAPS fields are scope variables. In the case of SERVICE and IDENTIFIER the emit correctly uses the value of the scope variable as it is passed to the M/R.

However when I try to use the value of a scope variable as a key in the emitted document, the document is created with the scope variable name (as opposed to it's value).

```
return emit({
    service: SERVICE,
    date: _this.value.date,
    identifier: _this.value[IDENTIFIER]
  }, {
    errors: {
      count: 1,
      type_breakdown: {
        SINGLES_ONLY: {
          count: 1
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: I am a JavaScript noob so this may be a simple JavaScript thing.

Comment: This is a JS thing, it is not so simple to fix though, it is the way JS works, the best method is to not build your document on-demand like that but to form it uup slowly allowing the possibility for those variables to be used correctly by the JS engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the shortcut syntax for creating objects in JavaScript, the left hand side/property name is always interpreted as a literal value, regardless of quotes.

For example:

```
var d={ name: "Aaron" }
```

Is equivalent to:

```
var d={ "name" : "Aaron" }
```

As there are two ways to set a property value:

1. `obj.propertyName=value`
2. `obj["propertName"]=value`

You have to construct your object using the second syntax, at least in part.

```
var errors={
      count: 1,
      type_breakdown: { }
      }
    };
var countObj={ count:1 };
errors.type_breakdown[SINGLES_ONLY]=countObj;

// pass results to emit call
```