# Array declaration using a variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I've this:

```
var tmp = "Test";
```

and want that:

```
Books.update({_id: data._id},{$set:{tmp: [0,0,0,0,0]}});
```

Now I get an array like this: tmp: [0,0,0,0,0]
But I want that: Test [0,0,0,0,0]

Have somebody an idea how I can do that?

Comment: A very similar question I answered a couple of days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441723/how-to-use-scope-variables-as-property-names-in-a-mongo-map-reduce-emit/18442391#18442391

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var tmp = "Test",
    set = {};

set[tmp] = [0,0,0,0,0];
Books.update({_id: data._id},{$set: set});
```