# mongodb mapreduce scope - ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, mongodb, scope, mapreduce

I'm trying to use an external object inside mongodb map/reduce functions. If the object has a variable which it should access, an error occurs.

For example:

```
var conn = new Mongo();
var db = conn.getDB("test");

var HelperClass = function() {
  var v = [1, 2, 3];

  this.data = function() {
    return v;
  };
};

var helper = new HelperClass();

var map = function() {
  helper.data().forEach(function(value) {
    emit(value, 1);
  });
};

var reduce = function(key, values) {
  var count = 0;
  values.forEach(function(entry) {
    count += entry;
  });
  return count;
};

db.test.mapReduce(map, reduce, {
  out: "temp",
  scope: {
    helper: helper
  }
});
```

The output from mongodb:

> map reduce failed:{   "errmsg" : "exception: ReferenceError: v is not
>   defined",     "code" : 16722,     "ok" : 0 } at
>   src/mongo/shell/collection.js:970

Is it an expected behavior? Is there any other way to use external objects in mapReduce?

Answer (score 1):

What's casuing the problem is this function:

```
var HelperClass = function() {
  var v = [1, 2, 3];

  this.data = function() {
    return v.data;
  };
};
```

Since:

```
return v.data;
```

Is in a different scope to the real variable which is actually `this.v.data`.

Comment: I mistakenly tried to access v.data which doesn't exist (I'm sorry, I was going to "return v" instead, edited the question now), but v is not accessible anyway. However, if I run print(helper.data()); outside of mapReduce, it works fine. Shouldn't it then work from mapReduce as well?

Comment: @silyevsk ah I didn't see that it wasn't part of the system.js collection. No, it will not work, map reduce is a completely differnent environment and different scopes

Comment: @silyevsk if you want this to work you will need to use the system.js collection saving the function to that

Comment: I'll try system.js, thanks! Though I still don't understand why it doesn't work, I thought that passing helper variable via the scope parameter to mapReduce should work.

Comment: @silyevsk It doesn't work because the shell script is not MongoDB and Map Reduce is MongoDB, it is two completely separate envos