# Map Reduce not giving results for NodeJS MongoDB native driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mapreduce

My map-reduce function in NodeJS is like this:

```
 exports.getDistinctURLCount = function(params, callback){
    var mapFunction = function(){
        var bucket = 10;
        emit(Math.floor(parseInt(this.xyz)/bucket), {count: 1});
    };

    var reduceFunction = function(key, values){
     var urlCount = 0;
     if(values != undefined){
       values.forEach( function(value) {
         urlCount += value.count ;
       });
     }
     return urlCount;
    };

    var finalizeFunction = function (key, reducedVal) {
       if(isNaN(reducedVal)){
        return reducedVal.count
       }else{
        return reducedVal
       }
      };

    var output = {
       out: {"inline":1},
       finalize: finalizeFunction
      };

      return mongoMan.mapReduceFunction("clients", mapFunction, reduceFunction, output, function(err, result){
        if(err){
          callback(err, null);
        }else{
          console.log(result);
          callback(null, result);
        }
 }
```

MongoMan is a different file, that accepts map-reduce functions:

```
exports.mapReduceFunction = function(collection, map, reduce, options, callback){
  _getModel(collection).mapReduce(map, reduce, options, function(err, docs){
    _prepResponse(err, docs, callback);
  });
}
```

The map reduce query successfully runs in Mongo Shell, however when called through NodeJS, it doesn't yield any result. Not even blank.

Am I doing anything wrong in passing the map, reduce functions?

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems:

Passing the function as arguments to another function -

```
return mongoMan.mapReduceFunction("clients", mapFunction.toString(), reduceFunction.toString(), output, function(err, result){
    if(err){
      callback(err, null);
    }else{
      console.log(result);
      callback(null, result);
    }
```

Another problem was the scope of variable - Refer here [How to use variables in MongoDB Map-reduce map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273379/how-to-use-variables-in-mongodb-map-reduce-map-function)

Also, I am using Mongoose. So, here's how mapReduce is handles in Mongoose - [Mongoose API](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html)