# How to send (pass) variables from client to server (within the mapReduce function in server) in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mapreduce

I am working on GeoSpatial project which I am using MongoDB as database and Meteor for creating my app. I have used mapReduce in my query. in order to visualize the result of query I put Google map API in the meteor. To make long story short, I want to get some location as an Input from meteor app and when I click on the button, see the result in Google Map API (which is placed in Meteor app.

Now my problem is that I cannot pass the variables (the ones that I got from textbox) from client function to server side in meteor.

Here is some part of my code in client side (here I have passed text1 and text2 as an argument in call function):

```
var text2 = document.getElementById("coords2").value;
var text1 = document.getElementById("coords1").value;
Meteor.call("doMapReducePointQuery", text1, text2, function(error, result){

  if(error){
    console.error(error)
  }
  else{
    console.log("It works!");
  }....// continued
```

and here is the part of the code in server side:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    'doMapReducePointQuery': function(txt1,txt2) {

      pxx=parseInt(txt1);
      pyy=parseInt(txt2);

      console.log(pxx); **// here I can see the pxx and pyy**
      console.log(pyy);

      var mapFn = function () { **// in this function I cannot get the pxx and pyy**

        var px = -83.215; // here I just manually set the number, here where i want to get value from the text box and set it to px and py 
        var py = 41.53;

        var key= this._id;
        var value={
          id:this._id, 
          type: this.type,                   
        };

        if (this.geometry.minlon <= px && px <= this.geometry.maxlon && this.geometry.minlat <= py && py <= this.geometry.maxlat) {
          emit(key, value);                   
        }                   
      };

      var reduceFn = function (key, value) { ....... // continued
```

As I mentioned in comments within the code, I can pass txt1 and txt2 to the  `doMapReducePointQuery` method but the I cannot access then access the coordinates within my mapReduce `mapFn` function. **I need to use txt1 (px) and txt2 (py) values in `mapFn`.**

I did some research about how to make a variable, global in meteor, some of the people used "scope", but they did not mentioned how.

I would be really appreciated if somebody help me!

Comment: The solution appears to be [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11449352/2805154) - using the `scope` parameter in m-r.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried the scope but still have problem.